# Docker containerized Laravel Application connecting to local mysql server

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, localhost, database-connection

I have containerized my Laravel application and now I want to connect it to my Local MySQL server

1. I have exposed the MySQL server by editing ```"/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf" file

   "# skip-external-locking"

   "bind-address            = 0.0.0.0"
2. I have created dedicated user by

   CREATE USER 'new_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpassword';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'new_user'@'%'; 
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

once I trying to run migrations on my app, there is a time out triggering 
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out"

Please assist me on this matter

Thanks

Comment: Try to connect with you network ip address 192.168.*.*

Comment: yap.Still getting "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to your local database , you call give `host.docker.internal` in the place where we provide database url . Then give the db you want to specify along with db username and db password.

Comment: It gives "PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve" error

Comment: plase can share your .env

Comment: As you said I have added host.docker.internal to "DB_HOST".......->

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laradockdb
DB_USERNAME=laradock_user
DB_PASSWORD=laradock

Comment: ```DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.interna
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root``` Laradock default database name default

Comment: if you use laradock change this => 
DATA_PATH_HOST=./data   in laradock/.env and MYSQL_VERSION=5.7

Comment: No I'm using separate docker-compose file. not laradock